# How to add startup apps in Windows 10 if Task Manager is replaced with SysInternals Process Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, sysinternals, process-explorer

I'm on Windows 10 1809.  I have installed SysInternals Process Explorer and have it substituted for Task Manager.

I now need to add an application to the "Startup" list.  I can see the Startup list in Control Panel, but I don't see a way to add to that list.  The only way I'm aware of to add to that list is through Task Manager, which I now cannot get to, and there doesn't appear to be a substitute option in Process Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 64-bit

all users:

```
"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"

"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp"
```

current user:

```
"%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

"F:\Users\_9doug\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit

You could also use the registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```